# Swift tableview at delete cell process indexPath.row problem

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My question about tableview cell deleting process. When I try to delete cell with button, tableview first cell is deleted because of `let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)` How can I delete clicked button's cell? I can't find any way to take clicked row. Can anyone help me?

```
    @objc func deleteAction() {


    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    _ = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        if countPriceArray[indexPath.row] >= 1 {
            let ord = arraysForFiyat[indexPath.row]
            let splitOrd = ord.components(separatedBy: " ₺")
            let intOrd = splitOrd.map{ Int($0) ?? 0 }
            sum = sum - intOrd[0]
            UserDefaults.standard.set(arraysForUrun, forKey: "urunadi")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(arraysForFiyat, forKey: "urunfiyat")
            tableView.reloadData()

            if countPriceArray[indexPath.row] > 1 {
                countPriceArray[indexPath.row] -= 1
                tableView.reloadData()

            }else if countPriceArray[indexPath.row] == 1 {
                arraysForUrun.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                arraysForFiyat.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                countPriceArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arraysForUrun, forKey: "urunadi")
                UserDefaults.standard.set(arraysForFiyat, forKey: "urunfiyat")
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: @thisIsTheFoxe I want to make it with button action commit editing code works I know it but I want to ask how can I take indexPath.row of clicked cell's button?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

> In Tableview delegate Method cellForRowAt

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell") as! CustomCell
        cell.btnAction.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.btnAction.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionClicked(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return cell
    }
```

> Method of Button Action

```
@objc func buttonActionClicked(sender : UIButton) {
        let index = IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0)
        print("Sender tag is :- \(sender.tag)")
    }
```

**Note :- Add Tag to you button in indexpath and then try to use it for fetching indexpath of the selected button.**

Comment: I find it Thank you for help.

Comment: Be aware that this way causes unexpected behavior if cells can be inserted, deleted or moved.

Comment: @vadian I tried lots it seem working.. Why is this make this kind of behavior ?

Comment: Because for example when a cell is inserted  with `insertRows(at:` the method `cellForRowAt` is not necessarily called again for the other cells so the index path  can change silently.

Comment: @vadian I understand now. Is there any way to fix that how can I call again cellForRowAt function? (when I try to add more items count will be change wrongly)

Comment: A more reliable way is a callback closure, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58098923/how-to-get-index-path-on-click-of-button-from-uitableview-in-swift-5/58100909#58100909